# How to solve oscillation in random walk?

Tags: random-walk, random-graphs

I execute a random walk on complete graph, the L2 norm between the old and the new vectors (p(t+1)-p(t)) still decreases till the iteration x and after they go to increases, then again decreases an so one?

DOES this means something? how can I interpret that? When can I Stop the random walk in this case

Comment: what do you mean after they go to increases? doesn't p(t+1)-p(t) go to 0?

Comment: the difference looks likes it oscillates. I simulate now for big epsilon. The primarily results says, it still oscilliate till an iteration k and then it works as expected and the p(t+1)-p(t) tends to 0

Comment: I think a random walk should converge  (see condition in answer) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Convergence_speed_to_the_stationary_distribution   speed of convergence may be slow however

Answer (score 0):

I think I see your point so the theorem about random walks converging requires 1 other point (also see markov chains) that for large enough t'  and t>t' there is non zero probability that starting at i we would be at j for all i,j
see en.wikipedia.org/wiki/… basically do a Jordan decomposition / eigenvalue decomposition of your markov matrix (or possibly a power of such that each entry is strictly positive) then try to solve (A^l)x=px where p has absolute value 1 A^l has all positive entries and size 1 Jordan blocks (i.e it has an eigenvalue decomposition) moreover it also has row sum 1 this implies x=1 by looking at largest entry of x so A^l has only 1 eigenvalue of magnitude 1 so A has only 1 eigenvalue of multiplicity 1 (other eigenvalues strictly less than 1) and hence disappear in the limit

Comment: sorry can explain more? i cant capt your idea please

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Convergence_speed_to_the_stationary_distribution
basically do a Jordan decomposition / eigenvalue decomposition of your markov matrix  (or possibly a power of such that each entry is strictly positive)   then try to solve (A^l)x=px  where p has absolute value 1   A^l has all positive entries and size 1 Jordan blocks (i.e it has an eigenvalue decomposition)  moreover it also has row sum 1    this implies x=1 by looking at largest entry of x  so A^l has only 1 eigenvalue of magnitude 1 so A has only 1 eigenvalue of multiplicity 1 (others

Comment: eigenvalues strictly less than 1) and hence disappear in the limit